# Show/hide listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I am using listview in my activity. Now i need to hide the listview for a particular period of time and
then it needs to display. Its similar to our video players where seekbars while hide automatically and
when the user touches it will get display na similar i need to achieve in my activity. Instead of seekbar i 
need to hide my listview from the screen.Simply show/hide listviews in alternative touches. Am a newbiew. So Guide me in achieving this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have some View like a video player's play view.

```
View alwaysAppearingView;
```

And you have your listView, which you want to hide automatically after delay.

```
ListView listView;
```

Let's implement OnTouchListener for the alwaysAppearingView;

```
  alwaysAppearingView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    listView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        listView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // or View.INVISIBLE as Jason Leung wrote
      }
    }, 3000);
    return true;
  }
  });
```

You are checking each touch, when touched, you make listView visible and, if you have no touches for 3000 milliseconds (3sec), listView is disappearing.
Try it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this code it's showing null pointer exception.

Comment: You have xml layout in your project. You should initialize `alwaysAppearingView` with view from layout using view's ID. It looks like `alwaysAppearingView = findViewById(R.id.always_appearing_view);` Add this code to `onCreate` method of your Activity and make sure ID in xml `android:id="@+id/always_appearing_view"` is the same as you wrote in `R.id.always_appearing_view`. You have to initialize listView too. If you write xml code for main view and onCreate method, I can answer more detailed.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure what you want exactly, but to hide any Views in Android, simply set the visibility :)

```
listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or View.INVISIBLE, if you want the view still occupy the space in the screen

```
listview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

to make it come back

```
listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: What i need to achieve is while playing videos our seekbar will hide automatically and when we touch it will display na, like that i want to display my listview. Is my question clear now

Comment: u can hide the listitems like that, but hiding and showing the listview is somewhat difficult!!instead u can use toggle button..